# .po file doesn't change(translate) content on website

Tags: wordpress, po, mo

One theme that I use for my WP website has .po files for language. I trying to download to my localhost .po file to edit it(translate it) and upload back to host. The problem is that when I upload that file again nothing change on the site. Like I didn't tranlsated it. I download and upload both *.po* and *.mo* files.

I use PoEdit and I have no idea why is this.

Comment: What are file names when you download them, and what are when you upload them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to rename them on actual language? I mena if you translate `en_EN.po` and `en_EN.mo` to let's say French when you upload them you must change their name like `fr_FR.po` and `fr_FR.mo`. Or whatever language you will use after translation.